# MongoServerClosedError: Server is closed

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, server

I'm trying to connect to my MongoDB database and return an array containing every document (json) from collection "myCollection". For that I have the following code:

```
const uri = "uri"; // Can't post real uri here
const client = new MongoDB.MongoClient(uri);

app.get("/api", (request, response) => {
    async function getData() {
        let result = [];
        try {
            await client.connect();
    
            const db = client.db("myDatabase");
            const collection = db.collection("myCollection");
            const cursor = collection.find({});
            for await (const item of cursor) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        finally {
            await client.close();
        }
        return result;
    };
    response.send(getData());
});
```

The problem is that it returns this error:

```
MongoServerClosedError: Server is closed
    at Server.command (myPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:157:22)
    at FindOperation.executeCallback (myPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\find.js:30:16)
    at myPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\operation.js:65:18
    at node:internal/util:411:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at node:internal/util:397:12
    at FindOperation.execute (myPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\operation.js:66:11)   
    at retryOperation (myPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:152:32) 
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async executeOperationAsync (myPath\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:107:20) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

Where `myPath` is the folder that contains my project files. By testing I have found out that if I remove the `for await...of` loop, then the error disappears.

Comment: Is the mongo service running on your server ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah The database is running on a cloud server. My Node.js server file is running locally.

Comment: So the mongodb on cloud server might be stopped

Comment: @SrushtiShah The thing is that I get all the results I want. If i put `console.log(result);` after the `for await...of` then It returns all the documents in the collection. But after that it gives an error and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, use `response.send(getData())`, where `getData()` is an asynchronous function. at this point the asynchronous operation has not completed. What actually happens is sending a Promise (rather than the result) to the client. Meanwhile, Node.js continues executing the event loop. in your code, This could cause the mongodb close before all the asynchronous operation complete.
so, a simple solution:

```
app.get("/api", async (request, response) => { //add async
    async function getData() {
        let result = [];
        try {
            await client.connect();
    
            const db = client.db("myDatabase");
            const collection = db.collection("myCollection");
            const cursor = collection.find({});
            for await (const item of cursor) {
                result.push(item);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        finally {
            await client.close();
        }
        return result;
    };
    const data = await getData(); //add this
    response.send(data);
});
```

by the way, you should not connect and close your mongodb connection in your request. you should do in global context.